# Http request with multiple ranges returning InvalidRange

Tags: http, range

I send a http request with multiple ranges like that "Range:bytes=0-10,20-30,40-50" and received a response like:

```
{
"code": "InvalidRange",
"message": "The requested range cannot be satisfied.",
"requestId": "88884ba4-eba9-47dc-b17a-dddc5f0e4a7f"}
```

However, if I set a single range block like "Range:bytes=0-100", I can receive the correct response with data bytes.

I'm pretty sure the range didn't exceed data boundary. Any idea how this happens?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the server doesn't support multiple ranges, or that it rejects requests that could be better served as a single bigger range (like the one in your example).